# CPLEX how do i write the equation for such indexing

Tags: indexing, sequence, cplex, opl

I am trying to write the following constraint in cplex ide.

`x_ij +x_ji == 1` (either car `i` infront of car `j` or car `j` infront of car `i`) for all `i` and `j` such that `i<j`

they are all assigned starting position in sequence that bently is 1 honda is 2 bmw is 3 and audi is 4.

what i have tried..

```
{string} cars = ["bently" "honda" "bmw" "audi"];

dvar int x[cars][cars] in 0..1;

    forall(i in cars)
      forall(j in cars:i<j)
        x[i][j] + x[j][i] == 1;
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you label your constraints you'll get relaxations that will help you to debug:

```
forall(i in cars)
     ctA:-aps <= ((numcars - sum(i in cars, j in cars:i < j) x[i][j]) - inicarposition[i]);
   forall(i in cars)
     ctB:((numcars - sum(i in cars, j in cars:i < j) x[i][j]) - inicarposition[i]) <= aps;
```

Comment: i cannot seem to set breakpoints, i doubleclicked the left margin & the line number but the blue dot indicating a break point does not show..

Comment: being able to view the constraints helps alot, thanks alex

Answer (score -1):

could

```
{string} cars = {"bently" ,"honda" ,"bmw" ,"audi"};

dvar int x[cars][cars] in 0..1;

subject to
{
    forall(ordered  i,j in cars)

        x[i][j] + x[j][i] == 1;

}
```

help ?

Or

```
using CP;

{string} cars = {"bently" ,"honda" ,"bmw" ,"audi"};

dvar int position[cars] in 0..3;

subject to
{
    allDifferent(position);

}
```

?

Comment: my original code did not have any errors detected but there is no solution. I tried what you have suggested but it still does not have a solution. I have edited the question with the full code.. hope to get some help. thanks in advance